# Display Widget based on Current State in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The basic intention I have is to display a widget based on my current state. Let's say, when the user clicks a button, I use the `setState()` method to set the value of a `currentPage` to `2`.

```
onTabChangedListener: (position, title, color) {
       setState(() {
         currentPage = position;
...
```

When it is `2`, I want to display the following widget instead of the one currently being displayed. I have tried `if/else` cases, but it doesn't seem to be the way. I have also gone over this and this, but I am not clear with the implementation. I understand how stateful-widgets work - just need a code example that's similar to my problem.

```
// Widget I want to display when currentPage state is changed to 2.

  Widget _buildContent() {
    return Positioned(
      bottom: 50,
      left: 25,
      right: 25,
      child: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
//            _buildTextField("Some Text"),
            _buildLoginButton(),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: "Some Text",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 10.5,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  letterSpacing: 1,
                ),
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: "Another Text",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Note: Full Page of my Current Code is [available here](https://gist.github.com/Eshpelin/3912a016547eccca288395315f1cdd5b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that I used in my code to do that. Put all pages that you want to display in a `Stack` with `Offstage` Widget. `Offstage` widget will hide (make it "offstage") if the offstage condition is true.

```dart
Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Offstage(
              offstage: 0 != _currentBottomBarIndex,
              child: PageOne(),
            ),
            Offstage(
              offstage: 1 != _currentBottomBarIndex,
              child: PageTwo(),
            ),
            Offstage(
              offstage: 2 != _currentBottomBarIndex,
              child: PageThree(),
            ),
            Offstage(
              offstage: 3 != _currentBottomBarIndex,
              child: PageFour(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes good sense. But, where do I put this stack and how do I call/use this? Anywhere inside my `MessageScreenState` class? I am not being able to understand how to use this.

Comment: Yes, put it inside build method of any State class. That should work